# No *shutdown* function in KDE

Tags: permissions, kde4

My base system is Gentoo amd64, up to date. Before the upgrade, I have the *shutdown* button in the KDE menu. But after the upgrade, this button is gone...I think it is because of the permission settings are wrong. The user account I used is in the *user* group. But I have no idea how the set the permission. I even tried to delete the KDE configuration files in the user directory and try to re-configure everything, but does not work.

Comment: You can try [this](http://superuser.com/questions/400185/fix-kde-permissions-after-sudo-startx). Have you tried to create a new account to see if the shutdown button is there?

Comment: @Alko, I have tried. No *shutdown* button for the new user. I think it is a system wide configuration issue.

Comment: I have find out this issue is related to polkit, not KDE itself...however I still cannot find a fix :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The configuration file /etc/config/kdm/kdmrc has the following section:

```
[Shutdown]
# The command (subject to word splitting) to run to halt the system.
# Default is "/sbin/shutdown -h -P now"
# HaltCmd=
# The command (subject to word splitting) to run to reboot the system.
# Default is "/sbin/shutdown -r now"
# RebootCmd=
# Whether it is allowed to shut down the system via the global command socket.
# Default is false
# AllowFifo=true
# Whether it is allowed to abort active sessions when shutting down the
# system via the global command socket.
# Default is true
#AllowFifoNow=false
```

Un-comment the "AllowFifo=true" line, then the system shutdown as it used to before the latest upgrade.
Source and [info](http://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-t-869641-start-0.html) As long as this is correct you can add a shutdown launcher.

Comment: I am not using *kdm*, I use *lightdm*. So I don't have this config. file at all :(

Answer (score 0):

Switch to `systemd` fix this permission issue.